# We use MongoDB 3.6 community version, How can i get the number of hits on single collection as well as bandwith usage?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

Is it possible to get the number of hits on single collection as well as bandwith usage in mongodb ?

Comment: Interesting question (+1). The NoSQL bandwagon is truly grinding to a shuddering halt under the weight of questions like this - these systems are great for astronaut programmers who work for large web-based companies and don't have to or want to think about instrumentation. The reality is that without instrumentation, databases are little better than bitbuckets.

Comment: contd... You might want to try PostgreSQL's JSONB functionality in conjunction with the [stats available](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html). Not sure how it works with JSON tables - AFAIK, JSONB collections are pretty much like normal tables. If you decide to try this route, you may want to check beforehand - I wouldn't want to give you a bum steer! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: There are a number of [collection-level metrics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#basic-stats-lookup) and [index usage stats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexStats/) available in MongoDB, but hits and bandwidth sound like metrics more applicable to a web UI/API. Do these links cover the sort of metrics you are after? If not, please edit your question to include more specific examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation section for [Analyzing Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/), another for [Monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/), and one specifically for [free monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring/).

You can also run the command `db.serverStatus()` to retrieve server statistics.